# p:dataTable is not displaying result

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml

JSF2.2 project deployed on the Wildfly 8.2.1, I am using the primefaces 6.2. When following code is diplayed on the browser it does not show any result even not the header.

diplayResult.xthml

```
<h:form id="form">
    <div style="border: 1">
        <h:messages globalOnly="true" errorClass="err" warnClass="warn"
            infoClass="info"></h:messages>
        <h:messages globalOnly="false" errorClass="err" warnClass="warn"
            infoClass="info"></h:messages>
    </div>
    <h:panelGrid>
        <h:outputLabel id="quantity1"> Line:</h:outputLabel>
        <h:message for="quantity1"></h:message>
        <h:inputText id="quantity"
            value="#{dActivityRelatedController.quantity}"></h:inputText>
        <h:message for="quantity" errorClass="err" warnClass="warn"
            infoClass="info"></h:message>
        <h:commandButton
            action="#{dActivityRelatedController.getDndActivitySetupList()}"
            value="list"></h:commandButton>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>

<h:form id="form2">
    <p:dataTable var="activitySetup" value="#{dActivityRelatedController.activitySetupList}">
        <f:facet name="header">
                         Activity Setup List
                    </f:facet>
        <p:columnGroup type="header">
            <p:row>
                <p:column />
                <p:column />
                <p:column colspan="2" headerText="------Import Dem------" />
                <p:column colspan="2" headerText="------Import Det------" />
                <p:column colspan="2" headerText="------Export Dem------" />
                <p:column colspan="2" headerText="------Export Det------" />
                <p:column headerText="status" />
            </p:row>
            <p:row>
                <p:column headerText="Last Year" />
                <p:column headerText="This Year" />
                <p:column headerText="From Activity Grp" />
                <p:column headerText="To Activity Grp" />
                <p:column headerText="From Activity Grp" />
                <p:column headerText="To Activity Grp" />
                <p:column headerText="From Activity Grp" />
                <p:column headerText="To Activity Grp" />
                <p:column headerText="From Activity Grp" />
                <p:column headerText="To Activity Grp" />
                <p:column headerText="" />
            </p:row>
        </p:columnGroup>

        <p:column>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{activitySetup.IMP_ACT_GROUP}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{activitySetup.IMP_ACT_GROUP}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{activitySetup.IMP_ACT_GROUP}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{activitySetup.IMP_ACT_GROUP}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{activitySetup.IMP_ACT_GROUP}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{activitySetup.IMP_ACT_GROUP}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{activitySetup.IMP_ACT_GROUP}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{activitySetup.IMP_ACT_GROUP}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{activitySetup.IMP_ACT_GROUP}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>

</h:form>
```

JSF basic tags are working, as below code.

```
<h:form id="datatableform">

    <h:dataTable
        value="#{dActivityRelatedController.activitySetupList}"
        var="activitySetup">

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">From Activity Grp</f:facet>                  
  #{activitySetup.IMP_ACT_GROUP}
```

```
    </h:dataTable>

</h:form>
```

When I check the diplayed page using firebug, then the complete primefaces code is displayed on the browser that is written on the diplayResult.xthml. That should be converted into equivalent html tags

Comment: Tried using less columns? Does it work then? No? You at least improved on the [mcve] and it is easier to look into. Still it is not a [mcve] so. Does it work when not useing a columngroup? Compared with the PF showcase?

Comment: @Kukeltje, thanks for quick response, but I have tried with less columns still the same result.

Comment: Then please improve your question by removing all superfluous columns AND make it into a real [mcve]

Comment: ah and what do you see in the client-side html source?